# Java Spring STOMP: Set broker IP

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a Java application using Spring that uses Websocket, which works fine as long as RabbitMQ runs in the same machine as tomcat.

How can I set the IP for RabbitMQ ? I am reading the documentation and I don't find it.

My current configuration is very similar to the [one in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-enable)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket/spring-websocket.xsd">

    <websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/portfolio">
            <websocket:sockjs/>
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /queue"/>
    </websocket:message-broker>

</beans>
```

How can I set the IP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You are using simple broker(<`websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /queue"/>`). Try to use below settings :

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
      <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
     <websocket:stomp-broker-relay prefix="/topic"
           relay-host="${websocket.relay.host}" relay-port="61613" client-login="user" client-passcode="passwd" system-login="user" system-passcode="passwd"
           heartbeat-send-interval="20000" heartbeat-receive-interval="20000"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

This configuration will help you adding ip. You might also need to add inbound and outbound channel configuration as default channel is one.Under load on a single channel response will be very slow. 
Insert below snippet in between `<websocket:message-broker> and </websocket:message-broker>` tags :

```
<websocket:client-inbound-channel>
<websocket:executor core-pool-size="50" max-pool-size="100" keep-alive-seconds="60"/>
</websocket:client-inbound-channel>
<websocket:client-outbound-channel>
<websocket:executor core-pool-size="50" max-pool-size="100" keep-alive-seconds="60"/>
</websocket:client-outbound-channel>
<websocket:broker-channel>
<websocket:executor core-pool-size="50" max-pool-size="100" keep-alive-seconds="60"/>
</websocket:broker-channel>
```

Also you will need to add login credentials in case your rabbitmq server is a different from application. For this you need to change configuration file. You can get this in RabbitMQ documentation