# websocket failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am using ec2, spring websocket using socksJS is working fine in local.
I have already tried below things.
1. I dont have any load balancer which is blocking TCP. Request is directly going to ec2 server
2. Use true IP in place of ec2 server name.

while server its giving following issue in chrome console, there is no error in application server logs

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://ec2-XX-X-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ws/963/kaidmvd9/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Javascript

```
app.service('SocketService', function(httpService,$rootScope,SoundService) {
this.registerMe = function(callback){
    $rootScope.socket = new SockJS("/ws");
    $rootScope.stompClient = Stomp.over($rootScope.socket);
    $rootScope.stompClient.connect('guest', 'guest', function(frame1) {
        $rootScope.stompClient.subscribe('/user/'+$rootScope.loggedInUser.username+'/reply', function(frame2) {
            var msg = JSON.parse(frame2.body);
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }, 
    function(error) {
        console.log(error.headers.message);
    }
    );});
```

Spring xml

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app" >
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
        <websocket:sockjs />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic,/user" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Comment: Are you loading the web page from the same `ec2-XX-X-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com` domain? If not, this may be a CORS issue http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-fallback-cors

Comment: Yes, from same domain..

Answer (score 0):

Came to this through your T-Hub post, don't have enough reputation to add a comment else would have done that. Here's what you could try; use your EC2's private ip (find using `ifconfig`) to host the WebSocket endpoint.

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
      <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
     <websocket:stomp-broker-relay prefix="/topic,/user"
           relay-host="your-ec2-private-ip-addr" relay-port="80" heartbeat-send-interval="20000" heartbeat-receive-interval="20000"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Got help from:
[Java Spring STOMP: Set broker IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504410/java-spring-stomp-set-broker-ip)

Comment: It dint work for me. In logs it repeats below msg
DEBUG: org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder - Encoded STOMP command=CONNECT headers={accept-version=[1.1,1.2], login=[guest], heart-beat=[20000,20000], passcode=[guest]}
DEBUG: org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder - Encoded STOMP command=CONNECT headers={accept-version=[1.1,1.2], login=[guest], heart-beat=[20000,20000], passcode=[guest]}
INFO : reactor.tcp.netty.NettyTcpClient - CLOSED: [id: 0x1c3f4225, /172.16.228.141:56670 :> /172.16.228.141:8080]

Comment: I couldn't find solution, so finally i had to switch to long polling in place of web socket.